# problema de stack overflow oque fazer para corrigi-lo, melhorar desempenho, Java?

Tags: java

Sei que o stackoverflow é dado pelo estouro da memória mas estou com ele no java e não sei um modo de dar desempenho para que nãoo ocorra. Estou fazendo um software de calcular um simplex de programação linear, então tenho que mexer com arrays multidimensionais(matriz). Até a ultima chamada a qual deixarei comentado funciona tudo, ja quando chega na linha que falei que deixarei comentada, eu chamo uma função que foi utilizada denovo, ai da o stackoverflow pois ficará em um loop de funções chamando funções até a condição for valida. Segue o código, deixarei o comentario que falei em letras maiúsculas

```js
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package projetoplr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class ValidaDados {
    int ln;
    double [][] tabela;
    public ValidaDados(ArrayList data, int quantidade, int qtdRest[]) {
        int somaqtd = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < qtdRest.length; i++) {
            somaqtd = somaqtd + qtdRest[i];
        }
        //subString(data, quantidade);
        double[][] calcula = calcula(subString(data, quantidade),restricoes(data, somaqtd,quantidade,qtdRest),data, quantidade);
    }

    public String [] subString(ArrayList lista, int quantidade) {
       
        int conta = quantidade*2+1;
        String array[] = new String[conta];
        int cont = 1;
        int newExiste = 0;

        cont = 1;
        for(int i =0; i<conta;i++){
            int existe = lista.get(0).toString().indexOf("x" + cont);
            //System.out.println("existe:" + existe);
            String valor = String.valueOf(cont);

                if (i == 0) {
                    //Primeiro número do FO
                    array[i] = lista.get(0).toString().substring(0, existe);
                    newExiste = existe;
                    ln = Integer.parseInt(lista.get(0).toString().substring(0, existe)) * -1;

                } else if(i < quantidade) {
                    //outros números
                    array[i] = lista.get(0).toString().substring(newExiste + valor.length() + 1, existe);
                    newExiste = existe;
                    //Pegar o valor em negativo
                    if ((Integer.parseInt(array[i])*-1)<ln) {
                        ln = Integer.parseInt(array[i])*-1;
                    }
                    
                }
                else{
                        array[i] = "0";
                }
                cont++;   
                System.out.println(array[i]);
        } 
 
        return array;
    }

    public double [][] calcula(String [] fo ,int [][] restricoes,ArrayList lista,int quantidade){
        int z = 1;
        int [] foNew ;
        foNew = retornaInt(fo);
        double pegaPivot = 0;
        int guardaLn = 0,linePivot=0;
        double pivot = 0;
        int fim = quantidade * 2 +2;
        int lastLine = lista.size()-1;
        double[][] tabela = new double[lista.size()][quantidade * 2 + 2];
        
        
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                    for (int o = 0; o < fim; o++) {
                       if(i==0){
                           //primeiro receberá z
                           if(i==0 && o == 0){
                             tabela[i][o] = z;
                             }
                           else{
                              //depois o FO
                             tabela[i][o] = foNew[o-1]*-1;
                             //e o valor da tabela for igual ln pega a coluna em qe ln está
                             if(tabela[i][o]==ln){
                                 guardaLn = o;
                             }

                            }
                       }
                       else{
                           //Coluna Z
                           if(o==0){
                               tabela[i][o] = 0;
                                   }
                           //Outras colunas
                           else{
                               tabela[i][o] = restricoes[i-1][o-1];
                           }
                           //Se o(coluna) for igual a guarda ln(posição da coluna da ln)
                           if(o == guardaLn && i>1){
                               //System.out.println("foi");
                                 //Divide o B pelos elementos da coluna ln
                                 //pega a linha anterior e divide pelo b annterior
                                 pegaPivot = tabela[i-1][fim-1]/tabela[i-1][guardaLn];
                                 //Se a linha for a segunda(i=0)
                                 //armazenará a divisão de b por ln em pivot e pegará essa linha
                                 if(i == 2){
                                     pivot = pegaPivot;
                                     //Pegará a linha anterior(linha das operações)
                                     linePivot = i-1;
                                 }

                                 //Verifica o menor numero positivo e pega a linha
                                 else if(pegaPivot>0 && pegaPivot < pivot){
                                     pivot = pegaPivot;
                                     linePivot = i-1;
                                 }
                                  //System.out.println(pegaPivot+"pgpv");
                             }
                       }

                         // System.out.println(tabela[i][o]);

                    }
                    //tabela[i][o] 
                }
                //Pegando a ultima linha
                pegaPivot = tabela[lastLine][fim-1]/tabela[lista.size()-1][guardaLn];

                if(pegaPivot>0 && pegaPivot < pivot){
                pivot = pegaPivot;
                linePivot = lastLine;
                
                 }
                newLinePivot(tabela,linePivot, tabela[linePivot][guardaLn], fim,lista.size(),guardaLn);
              return tabela;
            }
    public void calcula2(int linhas, int colunas, int colunaMain, double [][]newTable){
        double [][] newTab = new double[linhas][colunas];
      
              int z = 1;
              int cont=0;
              double [] check = new double[colunas];
              for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
               for (int o = 0; o < colunas; o++) {
                   if(i==0 && o == 0){
                       newTab[i][o] = z;
                       
                   }
                   else{
                       newTab[i][o] = newTable[i][o];
                       if(i==0){
                       check[i] = newTable[i][o];
                          if(check[i]>0){
                              cont++;
                          }     
                               
                   }
                   }     }
              }
              if(cont!=colunas-1){
              pegaPivot(linhas,colunas,newTab);}
             else{
                 for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
               for (int o = 0; o < colunas; o++) {
                   System.out.println(newTab[i][o]);   
                   
               } 
              }
                  System.out.println("Melhor Solução");
              }
               newTab = null;
               return;
    }
    public int [][] restricoes(ArrayList lista, int somaqtd,int quantidade,int qtdRest[]) {
        String valor;

        int existe, newExiste = 0;
        int fim = quantidade * 2 +1;
        boolean aux=false;
        int armazena = 0, armazena2 = 0;
        int[][] restricoes = new int[lista.size()][quantidade * 2 + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int o = 0; o < fim; o++) {
                existe = lista.get(i + 1).toString().indexOf("x" + (o + 1));

                int existeRest = lista.get(i + 1).toString().indexOf("<=");
                if (o == 0) {
                    //Primeiro número de cada restrição
                    restricoes[i][o] = Integer.parseInt(lista.get(i + 1).toString().substring(0, existe));
                    newExiste = existe;
                } else {
                    if(o+1>quantidade*2){
                        restricoes[i][o] = Integer.parseInt(lista.get(i + 1).toString().substring(existeRest + 2, lista.get(i + 1).toString().length()));
                        
                    }else{
                        
                        if((o + 1) > qtdRest[i] && (o+1) <= (quantidade*2) && aux == true ){
                            restricoes[i][o] = 0;
                            if(o+1 == armazena+1 && i == armazena2){
                                aux = false;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                        if ((o + 1) > qtdRest[i] && (o+1) <= (quantidade*2) && aux == false) {      
                            restricoes[i][o] = 1;
                            armazena = o;
                            armazena2 = i+1;
                            aux = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            valor = String.valueOf(o + 1);
                            //Outros números das retrições
                            restricoes[i][o] = Integer.parseInt(lista.get(i + 1).toString().substring(newExiste + valor.length() + 1, existe));
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    newExiste = existe;
                }
                   
                    
            }
          
        }
            
    }

    public double [][] recalcula(double [][] tabela,int colunas,int linhas,double [] newlinepvt,int colunaP,int linePvt){
      double[][] newTabela = new double[linhas][colunas];   
     
        for(int i=0; i<linhas;i++){
            for(int o=0;o<colunas;o++){
                if(i!=linePvt){
                newTabela[i][o] = (newlinepvt[o]*(double)(tabela[i][colunaP]*-1))+(double)tabela[i][o];
                }
                else{
                newTabela[i][o] = newlinepvt[o];
                }
               
            }         
    }
    calcula2(linhas,colunas,colunaP,newTabela);
     newTabela = null;
    return newTabela;
    }
    
    public void newLinePivot(double [][] tabela,int linePivot, double elemPivot,int colunas,int linhas,int colunaP){
       // System.out.println(elemPivot+"lpvt");
       
        double [] newLpv = new double[colunas*2];
       
        //Pegando os números da linha pivot
        for(int i=0; i<colunas; i++){
        newLpv[i] =(double) tabela[linePivot][i]/elemPivot;
          
        }
        
    recalcula(tabela,colunas,linhas,newLpv,colunaP,linePivot);
     newLpv = null; 
     return;
    }
    
    public int [] retornaInt(String [] texto){
        int [] foNew = new int[texto.length*2];
        for(int i=0; i<texto.length;i++){
            foNew[i] = Integer.parseInt(texto[i]);
        }
        return foNew;
    }
    
    public void pegaPivot(int linha, int coluna, double[][] tabela) {
        double guardaLn = 2;
        int colLn=0;
        double [][] table = new double[linha*2][coluna*2];
        double pegaPivot2=0, pivot = 0;
        int linePivot=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < linha; i++) {
            for (int o = 0; o < coluna; o++) {
                table[i][o] = tabela[i][o];
                //restricoes[i - 1][o - 1];
                if (i == 0 && tabela[i][o] < guardaLn) {
                    guardaLn = tabela[i][o];
                    colLn = o;
                   // System.out.println(guardaLn);
                }
                //Se o(coluna) for igual a guarda colLn(posição da coluna da ln)
                if (o == colLn && i > 1) {
          
                    //Divide o B pelos elementos da coluna ln
                    //pega a linha anterior e divide pelo b anterior
                    pegaPivot2 = tabela[i - 1][coluna - 1] / tabela[i - 1][colLn];                    
                    //Se a linha for a segunda(i=0)
                    //armazenará a divisão de b por ln em pivot e pegará essa linha
                    if (i == 2) {
                        pivot = pegaPivot2;
                        //Pegará a linha anterior(linha das operações)
                        linePivot = i - 1;
                    } //Verifica o menor numero positivo e pega a linh
                    else if (pegaPivot2 > 0 && pegaPivot2 < pivot) {
                        pivot = pegaPivot2;
                        linePivot = i - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Pegando a ultima linha
        pegaPivot2 = tabela[linha - 1][coluna - 1] / tabela[linha - 1][colLn];

        if (pegaPivot2 > 0 && pegaPivot2 < pivot) {
            pivot = pegaPivot2;
            linePivot = linha - 1;

        }
/*AQUI ESTA O X, ELE COMENTADO FUNCIONA POIS NÃO HAVERÁ O LOOP DE FUNÇÕES JÁ SE EU DESCOMENTAR DA STACKOVERFLOW POIS ESSA FUNÇÃO CHAMARÁ A NEWLINEPIVOT > RECALCULA > CALCULA2 E ASSIM RESPECTIVAMENTE, COMO DAR DESEMPENHO PARA O LOOP DAS FUNÇÕES?

       //newLinePivot(table,linePivot,tabela[linePivot][colLn],coluna,linha,colLn);
       return;
    }

}
```

Comment: A causa mais comum de stack overflow em Java é que você entrou em uma recursão infinita. A segunda causa mais comum é que sua solução recursiva exige um espaço maior do que o disponível para armazenar a pilha de execução do que o necessário. Recomendo você olhar matematicamente para sua recursão: de um caso genérico, ela está se aproximando do caso básico a cada nível de entrada?, os casos ficam cada vez menores? Faz bastante tempo que estudei o simplex para, numa olhada rápida, falar onde (ou se) tem algum erro na sua implementação

Comment: Ah, sim, claro, lembre-se de que existem casos em que o simplex exige tempo muito grande (se não me engano, superpolinomial) para ser executado. Então... Valide primeiro se a sua entrada de testes é uma entrada adequada